# How to make vertical scrollview scroll-line visible?

Tags: android, scrollbar

[image]

I want to saw this scroll line in this box. I am using the ViewStub and in ViewStub I inflate
the android:layout="@layout/message_box" message_box.xml. Here is the code which i have done. I can't see this line.

```
  <ViewStub
            android:id="@+id/stub_box1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="30sp"                      
            android:inflatedId="@+id/box1"
            android:layout="@layout/message_box"/>
```

and in  android:layout="@layout/message_box" this line we use as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    style="@style/Theme.bmo.Item.Message"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:maxLines="2"
    android:scrollbars="vertical" 
    android:fadeScrollbars="false"/>
```

So please tell me how can I make it visible?

Answer (score 0):

Try to type this in your viewStub

```
 android:scrollbars="vertical"
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:scrollbars

Comment: hi i puted it in viewstub but can not see the line.

Comment: Try to wrap ViewStub with ScrollView and set height of ViewStub to match_parent and SrollView to wrap_content